# PHP 5.3: попытка купировать общеизвестные уязвимости

Tags: php, веб-программирование, apache, joomla, безопасность

Я полный новичок в PHP (и вообще не разработчик), но мой друг попросил меня о помощи со своим старым сайтом на `Joomla 1.5.22`, `PHP 5.3` и `Apache / 2.4.10` (он не может связаться c разработчиком, который создал его для него, а нанимать нового для переделки бюджет не позволяет).

Я не могу помочь ему перейти на последнюю версию PHP или Joomla, так как я полный ноль в веб-разработке.

Поэтому он спросил, могу ли я закрыть некоторые распространенные уязвимости, чтобы школо-хакеры не ломали старичка каждые пять минут.

Гугл привел меня к размещению таких строк в корневом php.ini:

```
disable_functions = chmod,chown,mkdir,exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source,allow_url_fopen,allow_url_include,stream_select,eval
expose_php = Off
enable_dl  = Off
```

Может ли этого быть достаточно, чтобы прикрыть сайт от создания рандомных `.php` файлов внутри проекта и каких-то общеизвестных практик взлома?

Заранее спасибо, товарищи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla 1.5.22 и PHP 5.3 весьма устарели. И пытаться закрыть уязвимости мелкими правками абсолютно бессмысленно. К тому же с каждым днем сайт становятся все более и более уязвимым. В любом случае миновать обновление Joomla и PHP не удастся. В сети можно найти большое количество статей на тему обновления Joomla и даже обновить будет значительно легче, чем лазить в коде и пытаться вносить какие-либо правки (особенно не обладая знаниями в данной области). А по поводу версии PHP можно уточнить у организации, которая предоставляет услугу хостинга. Они могут помочь со сменой версии PHP, если это возможно и тарифный план позволяет (ну и от хостера зависит конечно). При обновлении Joomla следует конечно учесть, что необходимо будет обновить и все используемые плагины и компоненты, а некоторые из них могут не работать с новой версией. И самое главное перед обновлением обязательно необходимо сделать бэкап (резервную копию) сайта, чтобы в случае чего - можно было вернуться к исходному состоянию.

Comment: Спасибо, потихоньку и сам начинаю понимать, что без обновления не обойтись. Сайт в docker-контейнере на VDS, так что в выборе версий товарищ не ограничен. Сам же проект под git. Так что, похоже, все необходимые для перехода условия имеются. Может, есть какие-то рекомендации по поводу выбора инструмента для перехода Joomla на последнюю версию? Возможно, чем-то пользовались сами? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: 1.) Для создания резервной копии сайта могу порекомендовать Akeeba Backup (бесплатный компонент) - в случае неудачных попыток обновления Joomla, действий злоумышленников и т.д. поможет восстановить сайт, либо вообще перенести на другой хостинг. 2.) Про обновление версии Joomla можете почитать тут (описано как раз с версии 1.5 и выше) http://blogwork.ru/obnovlenie-joomla/ На первых этапах будет сложнее, но в дальнейшем все проще и проще.

Answer (score 1):

Не зря же выходят заплатки(обновления). Если б можно было б двумя переменными конфига закрыть уязвимости,то никто б и не писал эти обновления. Плюс большинство сайтов взламываются не столько через уязвимый код,как через троян на компьютере хозяина сайта и ворующий пароли от фтп и т.д

Comment: @hunter Солгасен с Вами на 100%, но имеем то, что имеем :) Увы, думаю, многим знакомая в наших реалиях ситуация. Может быть, можно закрывать дыры путем урезки ненужного функционала, или тем же запретом на создание этих самых .php файлов, или обращение только к .php из корня.. Такое можно как-то осуществить?

Comment: Сначала посмотрите какие уязвимости и как эксплуатируются - есть и такие, которые есть в общих функциях - их можно закрыть как вы уже предложили. Но другие уязвимости так просто не закроешь.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov из того, что вижу - создаются .php файлы в рандомных директориях проекта, к ним обращаются извне. Как создаются - не знаю, но, видимо, `disable_functions` не помогает.

Comment: Чтобы Файлы не создавались нужно поставить права в директории на чтение, без записи.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov А это не чревато?.. Ничего не пойдет по известному месту на сайте, если запретить писАть?.. Там же кеши какие-то, еще что-то?..